# ssh to install and update computer lab

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a few labs with twenty or so computers I maintain in addition to my teaching load. I recently had to modify a setting so the students could use a piece of software. Is there a piece of software/script that I can supply a list of ip address, log in via ssh, and run my few lines in bash? One obstacle I found was forwarding the password in trying to script it.  I know I could use an ssh key, but a password would be more convenient for lab maintenance. TIA

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are searching for is called `parallel-ssh` or sometimes known as `pssh`.

```
parallel-ssh -AIi -h hostlist "sh" <myscript.sh
```

with a `hostlist` file as

```
host1
host2:port
user@host3
user2@host4:port
```

or use `-H host1 -H user2@host2` etc. on the command line. If you want, you may use `-l john` to have the same user john for all hosts.

`-A` prompts for password - be aware that it means using the same password for all clients! `-I` allows reading input streams - i.e. the script, `-i` returns standard output per client. `"sh"` is the command to run - the shell to read out the script you provide.